# Вопрос про enable_if_t

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Я знаю, что существует 2 варианта записи функции с std::enable_if_t

```
template<class Ty, class = std::enable_if_t<true>> // 1 вариант
struct my_struct{ };

template<class Ty, std::enable_if_t<true> = 0>     // 2 вариант
struct my_struct{ };
```

Но я не понимаю, в чем их разница и когда какой вариант использовать.
Можете объяснить на примерах?

Comment: *"2 варианта записи функции"* - а приведены 2 варианта записи структуры, причем обе не имеют смысла, а второй вообще не валидный.

Comment: Ответ зависит от предпочтений, и используемой версии (c++11/ 17/20...).  В 20-ке вообще предпочтительно использовать `requires`.

Comment: Второй способ не работает. Если написать `enable_if_t<true, int>`, то сработает.